# ruby on rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, relationship

I have two models as subject and teacher
Subject model as

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sclass
    has_many :subject_teachers
   attr_accessible :sub_name
end
```

and Teacher model as

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :sclass_teachers
   has_many :subject_teachers
  attr_accessible :fname, :lname, :mob, :email
end
```

and created their join table as subject_teacher as many to many relationship

```
class SubjectTeacher < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :teacher  
end
```

but i want to access teacher name in subject model / table how can i do it.
what and where did i write the perfect code so that i get specific teacher name to specific
subject as there are MANY TO MANY relationship?

Comment: Do you mean you need name of teacher with subject she takes in a specific class?

Comment: yes i need this but not in specific class as i says one teacher can teach many subject and one subject can be taken by many teachers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
has_many :teachers through => :subject_teachers
```

as @Hugo said

Comment: I added this given line insted of "has_many :subject_teachers " in my subject model but how can i access teacher name plz give me some hint

Answer (score 0):

You can access the teachers data from subject using the has_many :through relationship

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

What you say is a bit strange: you set up a many to many relationship, and require a specific teacher for a subject. So for a many to many relationship, you can get a list of teachers. And  from that list you could take the first one. But if you know there is at max one teacher for a subject, just a has_many is a lot more convenient.

You can access the teachers by using @subject.subject_teachers.teachers, where @subject is a Subject instance.

If you use a has-many-and-belongs-to-many relationship, you can omit the intermediate class. You only need that is the relationship has additional data, like a date and time.